# Execute the .exe file stored on Blob using execute process task

Tags: ssis, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to execute a .exe file stored on Blob storage from my SSIS Package using Execute process task. How can i achieve it, i don't see any options for accessing blob storage in the execute process task.

Comment: As a general troubleshooting approach, ask yourself how would you execute an .exe stored in Azure Blob Storage if SSIS *wasn't* involved?  My guess is you have to download the binary to local temporary storage and run it there

Comment: ...or copy the binary to an Azure VM and execute it there. By definition, Azure BLOB Storage has no Compute component.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Blob storage doesn't support processing(Executing packages) in the cloud. In your instance, you should download the .exe locally then run it. There are several ways to perform this task, depending on what solutions you are using. [Logic apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/), which allows you to use connectors with Blob storage, then perform actions on it(Download, upload etc..) based on conditions can be a good consideration. There other simpler ways to using the Storage SDKs. These options would help in the step of downloading rather than executing.